# onerror=string . $variable - fails

Tags: php, javascript

Why does this fail? It works when `onerror=` is not a variable but just a handtyped string.

```
<?php 
$error = "onerror='this.src = \'http://userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow2.png\'';";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
  echo "<img src='http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/3716_obj_sprite.gif?id=" . $i . "' alt='ID " . $i . "' title='ID " . $i . "'" . $error . "/>"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: "It fails" is far too vague a description. Please tell us what happens.

Comment: -check ' and "
-what has this to do with Java? Retag.

Comment: java and javascript is NOT the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$error = " onerror='this.src =\"http://userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow2.png\";'";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
  echo "<img src='http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/3716_obj_sprite.gif?id=" . $i . "' alt='ID " . $i . "' title='ID " . $i . "'" . $error . "/>"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I should use double quotes in HTML and single in PHP/JS, because that's te most general way.

Comment: @WouterJ you can use the one or the other, doesn't matter. And both are valid.

Answer (score -1):

Too many quotes. I'd rewrite it as follows, then you can spot errors easier:

```
<?php 
$error = "onerror='this.src = \'http://userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow2.png\'';";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
  echo "<img src='http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/3716_obj_sprite.gif?id=$i' alt='ID $i' title='ID $i' $error />"; 
} 
?>
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you want but it's easier to debug.

Comment: won't work. Now you get `onerror='this.src = 'url''` in the resulted HTML and that cannot...